# Use outsideClick to close custom directive popover

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, popover, using-directives

I have a popover as a custom directive that opens when an icon is clicked or hovered upon. When the icon is clicked the popover sticks, and will close if you click the icon again. Now I want to close the popover after it's clicked by clicking anywhere else but the popover. Below is my code...

MY CUSTOM DIRECTIVE

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('frontend.core.directives')
    .directive('myPopover', [
      function directive() {
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          templateUrl: '/frontend/core/directives/my-popover/my-popover.html',
          scope: {
            trigger: '@',
            title:'@'
          },
          transclude: true,
          link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
            //Need to hide content first
            elm.hide();
            //plugin binder
            $(scope.trigger).popover({
              html: true,
              trigger: 'hover click',
              placement: 'auto',
              content: function () {
                return elm.html();
              },
              title: function () {
                return scope.title;
              }
            });

          }
        };
      }
    ]);
}());
```

MY HTML

```
<div>
<i id="touch-details" class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
<my-popover trigger="#touch-details" my-popover-trigger="outsideClick" title="Details">
    <span>
       Inside of my popover
    </span>
</my-popover>
</div>
```

Please tell me what I need to do to enable closing the popover when clicked outside.

Comment: if your popover has some sort of overlay behind it, you could always check if that overlay has been clicked. Something like: `overlay.on('click', function() {myPopover.close();});` inside your directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the answer was already created. Just needed to tweak a little to match Angular syntax. So the '$' were changed to 'angular.element'.
For example...

```
$('body').on('click'
```

is equivalent to

```
angular.element('body').on('click'
```

See link...

http://jsfiddle.net/raving/jpsmegvL/

Answer (score 0):

Try injecting the 
$document into you directive and controlling in the event weather the click is inside the div holding the popup or outside the div. So something like this :

```
angular.module('frontend.core.directives')
    .directive('myPopover', [
      function directive($document) {
```

.......

```
  $document.on('click', function(event){

     event.originalEvent //This holds among other things where the click was made. If click was not made in the div containing the popup, then take an action
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

There is a property called popover-trigger that you can assign the property focus, which works as you want, on blur event. In addition, with ui-bootstrap you can easily use the popover and tooltips of bootstrap with angularjs like in this example:

```
<button popover-placement="top" 
        popover-title="Hello Word!"
        popover-class = "someClass"
        popover-trigger = "focus"
        uib-popover="I appeared on blur!"
        type="button" class="btn btn-default">
        Check
</button>
```